# Trying to get Server to Server Auth working for GoogleAPI without using client_secret.json file

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

Since we are storing all sensitive data now in our AWS datastore I'm trying to re-write a portion of our server app that hits the google-api sheets service to not use the `client_secret.json` to get the Auth. The new code I'm using compiles and runs but fails to return a token. It was based on some samples that I found online that "claimed" to have worked but definitely not working for me.

Here's my sample code:

```
private static ServiceAccountCredential GetCredentials()
{

        var clientEmail = "CLIENT EMAIL ADDRESS IN JSON FILE";
        var privateKey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----PRIVATEKEYDATA FROM JSON-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

        --For Read/ Write access...
        string Scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets";

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(clientEmail)
            {
                Scopes = new[] { awaitingFulfillmentScopes },
                User = "clientEmail",
            }.FromPrivateKey(privateKey));

        return credential;

}
```